# Openerp 7 to Odoo 8 - how to convert the database

Tags: odoo

I am trying to migrate my openerp7 to odoo 8. Do you know how can I convert the database version 7 to newer version 8?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Ask odoo company to do it from [openupgrade](https://upgrade.odoo.com/database/upload) through a valid contract by paying them money

Option 2:Try using Import/Export option from csv file

Option 3:Use odoo etl tool [link](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/etl/). You can find videos on you tube for odoo etl

Option 4: Use migration tool available from github [link is here](https://github.com/alca259/Odoo-Migration-Tool/releases)

Option 5: Use migration script [use this link](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/).  If you are on ubuntu(Linux OS) you can try this [link](http://blogs.teckzilla.net/2015/06/09/how-to-migrate-odoo-database-from-version-7-to-version-8/)

Option 6: You can try python anybox.migration.openerp 0.9 package, here is the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anybox.migration.openerp)