# Trouble upgrading odoo 8 to odoo 9

Tags: upgrade, odoo-8, putty, odoo

I have never used odoo, how do I upgrade from odoo 8 to odoo 9.

EDIT: I have found the answer to this question and have posted the steps along. I will develop a efficient process write it down as well as any difficulties if anyone would like that message or post me.

1. Backup the databases
2. Backup the server folder
3. Uninstall the odoo server
4. Install the new version of odoo and after stop the odoo service
5. Use a comparison tool to move changes from the Old addons folder to the new one. I use beyond compare for file and folder comparisons. This step probably will take more time around 30-40minutes tops to merge python and report files that were customized. Move existing modules in the old that don’t exist in the new addons folder.
6. Upgrade the database. For linux, start the odoo server with the –update=all parameter. For windows, as an administrator open the command prompt (cmd).  Change to the odoo server directory and start the server with odoo-server.exe –update=all to update the modules. This process will take a short while (1-2minutes max) and the database won’t be accessible by the client
7. After the database upgrade  you can start poking around your old modules you moved to the new to make sure that they where working. I had some  that where not working, reports screwed up, but majority where simple fixes. Finally, your up and running the latest version. This has taught me a major lesson, document all changes/fixes you make yourself to applications and also keep track of them in the source control. Now next thing I will be setting up my old local svn server to keep track of the changes I make to odoo and also changes I will be merging from the subsequent releases.

Comment: no your wrong. that link does not provide me an answer

Comment: Does this work for you? I get an error when updating, even with the standard modules installed.

Comment: Freddi are you trying to migrate the static content?

Comment: yes, just the basics, that fail. For example the table ir_model because there are fields missing.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the 5th point of my answer, take a look at it @Freddy

Answer (score 5):

You have several options for upgrading or migration. It is not an easy task:

1. **[Upgrade Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/upgrade_api.html) with the official API**. It is not for free. I have read on the website that the main steps are:

   - Creating a request
   - Uploading a database dump
   - Running the upgrade process
   - Obtaining the status of the database request
   - Downloading the upgraded database dump
2. [**OpenUpgrade**](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/). It is a migration tool, but it works only for the modules specified on the website.
3. **ETL tool** such as [Clover ETL](https://www.cloveretl.com/). Maybe too much work
4. **Migrate specific tables** by exporting them in a CSV file and import them back to the new Odoo version. This is useful if someone want to start from scratch, you will only need to import the main tables.
5. **Use the flag `--update=all`**. You say that you have used this way after upgrading Odoo to the version 9, but I do not recommend it. Even if you don't change the Odoo version, if you update all the modules at the same time you will have a high chance to get several errors. It is like the Openupgrade method, but it is worse because you do not take into account the migrations folder where all the migrations scripts are stored such [this one](https://github.com/OCA/pos/tree/9.0/pos_pricelist/migrations/8.0.1.1.0), just an example.

**NOTE:** And if you have programmed a custom module you must migrate it to the new version before the migration. If you have many custom modules the migration would be more expensive.

Comment: öpen upgrade hasnt got a version 8 to version 9 yet. and ODOO etl is series 8,0. am after 9,0??

Comment: You are right, you can use some other ETL tool such as Clover ETL

Comment: I have some issue. **Fallback on creating empty database** How to solve this problem? @ChesuCR

Answer (score 0):

Check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856233/openerp-7-to-odoo-8-how-to-convert-the-database/34149106#34149106). I have suggested many ways on how to migrate between odoo versions.