# Migrate Odoo CRM DB from V6 to V8

Tags: python, postgresql, migration, odoo

My boss give me a task to migrate a OpenERP V6 DB that have CRM installed on it and have CRM data to migrate it to V8 without any loss of the data

I need to know how to implement something like that or how to move the data and update the database from v6 to v8

update 1 :

i tried to use openupgrade ,, i have downloade migrate.py and run command
`python migrate.py --config=[openerp-server.conf] --database=[kamel] --run-migrations=7.0` but i alawys got an error

```
No user found in configuration
```

and here is my openerp-server.conf:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
addons_path = /Users/mostafa/Documents/odoo-develop/odoo8/addons,/Users/mostafa/Documents/odoo-develop/net2do_work,/Users/mostafa/Documents/odoo-develop/more_net2do,/Users/mostafa/Documents/odoo-develop/freelance_work,/Users/mostafa/Documents/odoo-develop/custom_addons
pg_path= /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible using standard tools. [Here](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/upgrade-to-openerp-odoo-8-52844) the same question. I don't know how I would have solved this problem. You need find difference between db v6 and v8. You can install clear odoo(6 and 8) with test data. After this you can compare data and tables from each module and write migration step by step.

Comment: This will be a boring exhausted thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856233/openerp-7-to-odoo-8-how-to-convert-the-database/34149106#34149106/).There are many ways on how to do this.But I am not sure whether this solution works for you but u  can just try out